# How to use "stream_get_line" multiple times?

Tags: php

I would like to declare multiple variables using the output of my script and the [stream_get_line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php) php function.

Example:

```
<?php

$fp = fsockopen("10.73.xxx.xxx", "23");

fputs($fp,"user\r");
sleep(1);
fputs($fp,"password\r");
sleep(1);

$content = stream_get_line($fp, 100, "user");
$content2 = stream_get_line($fp, 100, "password");


echo $content;
echo $content2;
?>
```

However, the script stops working after I use the stream_get_line once. How can I use it multiple times to grab multiple lines of output? It works fine if I remove the second stream_get_line function.

Comment: What is you use `\r\n` for line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code:

```
$fp = fsockopen("10.73.xxx.xxx", "23");

fputs($fp,"user\r");
sleep(1);
fputs($fp,"password\r");
sleep(1);

while(!feof($fp)) {
    $content = stream_get_line($fp, 100, "user");
    $content1 = substr($content, 10, 4);
    $content2 = substr($content, 15, 8);
}
```

I store the whole thing in the variable "content" and then build 2 extra variables "content1" and "content2", where I pull the desired output from the variable "content".

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
$fp = fsockopen("10.73.xxx.xxx", "23");

fputs($fp,"user\r");
sleep(1);
fputs($fp,"password\r");
sleep(1);

while(!feof($fp)) {
    $content = stream_get_line($fp, 100, "\n");
    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: Well, thats one variable then. I would like to declare multiple variables with multiple outputs. Example: Output after user\r should be stored in variable1, output after password\r should be stored in variable2 and so on.

Comment: @Brandon What does the streamed input that You want to parse look like? I showed You how to loop when streaming, now You should move on and figure the rest out...